# Adobe Air android mobile application not launching

Tags: android, apache-flex, air

I am trying a blank application made in flex 4.6 and air 3.3 on HTC wildfire S and as soon as the application s launched i get the message saying , application has stopped unexpectedly.

Approx a month ago , everything was working fine(approx a month or 2 ago with air 3.1 and android 2.3.3) and i was able to install every application made in flex on my phone.

Now i am not sure what is causing the problem , either adobe air updates or HTC wildfire rom updates which updated my phone from android 2.3.3 to android 2.3.5.

Although i have tried reversing both things , i have tried to do a blank application using old version of adobe air 3.1 and still it is not launching , also i have tried downgrading my phone from android 2.3.5 to android 2.3.3 and still not working.

I am totally stuck now clueless now where to look for.

I really need your help to resolve this thing as i have spent days googling and finding for a solution and trying downgrading phone.

Hope some one will help me out.

==========Below is error log from Android phone when i try to launch the app============

```
06-17 03:48:18.045: W/dalvikvm(2631): No implementation found for native Lcom/adobe/air/AIRWindowSurfaceView;.nativeOnFormatChangeListener (I)V
06-17 03:48:18.065: D/AndroidRuntime(2631): Shutting down VM
06-17 03:48:18.065: W/dalvikvm(2631): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400205a0)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeOnFormatChangeListener
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.nativeOnFormatChangeListener(Native Method)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.surfaceChanged(AIRWindowSurfaceView.java:683)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:557)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:348)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6973)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.view.SurfaceView.draw(SurfaceView.java:334)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6973)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1949)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1600)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1321)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1957)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4268)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-17 03:48:18.065: E/AndroidRuntime(2631):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-17 03:48:18.085: W/ActivityManager(118):   Force finishing activity air.testapp.debug/.AppEntry
06-17 03:48:18.585: W/ActivityManager(118): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4056ee18 air.testapp.debug/.AppEntry}
```

Comment: On IOS devices an error would show up in the "crash logs" when something like this happens. Assuming something similar happens on Android, would that shed any light on this problem?

Comment: Its working fine on iOS.

Comment: I was actually asking if there are crash logs you can look at on the Android device :)

Comment: Hi, Its working fine on iOS but not on Android. Plz let me know any more ideas/suggestions. In android debugger i can see an error saying ...... 06-17 03:48:18.045: W/dalvikvm(2631): No implementation found for native Lcom/adobe/air/AIRWindowSurfaceView;.nativeOnFormatChangeListener (I)V

Comment: Below are all lines from android phone log:

Comment: I have added full crash log data above. Please let me know if you get any hint from crash log.

Comment: All the other reports of this problem have to do w/either unsupported devices or a possibly a corrupted AIR install. Neither of which seem to be the problem here. But this got me thinking, maybe using the [captive runtime](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html) install (where AIR is bundled w/your app) would be worth trying. You also might consider filing a bug w/Adobe.

Comment: I have tried the app with captive runtime and without captive runtime. But Error is the same with both. Only thing is i can't figure out if the problem is with adobe air or android or htc updates.